# Getting null pointer exception while using page factory to intialize webelements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

The webelements are not getting initialized.

the code is given below:

HomePage.java

```
package crossword.pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import base.TestBase;

public class HomePage extends TestBase{

    @FindBy(xpath = "//title")
    WebElement homepageTitle;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class=\"top-links\"]//a[text()='Login']")
    WebElement loginLink;

    public HomePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public String gethomepagetitle() {
        return homepageTitle.getAttribute("title");
    }

    public void clickonLogin() {
        loginLink.click();
    }

}
```

HomePageTest.java

```
package testcases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import base.TestBase;
import crossword.pages.HomePage;

public class HomePageTest extends TestBase {

    public HomePageTest() {
        super();
    }

    HomePage homepage = new HomePage();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        TestBase.initialization();
    }

    @Test
    public void homepagetitletest() {
        System.out.print(homepage);
        String actualTitle = homepage.gethomepagetitle();
        String expectedTitle = "Books - Crossword - Crossword";
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
    }

    @Test
    public void clickonloginlink() {

        homepage.clickonLogin();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void exit() {
        teardown();
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is:

FAILED: clickonloginlink
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)
    at crossword.pages.HomePage.clickonLogin(HomePage.java:25)
    at testcases.HomePageTest.clickonloginlink(HomePageTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)

Answer (score 0):

When we doing PageFactory design pattern we should initialise every page by page factory method.Here you should get null point exception when you initialise as **HomePage homepage = new HomePage();**

You should initialise as 
**HomePage homePage**;

**homePage=PageFactory.initElements(Webdriver driver,HomePage.class);** in your HomePageTest.java

Please remove **= new HomePage();** in your code

Comment: homePage=PageFactory.initElements(driver,HomePage.class);

Comment: That's totally incorrect. Both methods are valid, either by initializing elements in the constructor and passing object, or passing class and letting PageFactory create an instance of the class. The problem here is that OP's passing `null` driver to `initElements` method